# Symfony2 Multiple Select on Form Builder default values

Tags: php, forms, symfony

This has been boggling my mind for hours now, I am using Symfony2's form builder!

```
->add('technicians', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => array(
                    1 => 'Test'
                ),
                'multiple'  => true,
                'data' => array(
                    1 => true
                )
            ))
```

Image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUi7H.png

But when I use Strings as keys in the array, it magically stops working.

Like so:

```
->add('technicians', 'choice', array(
                'choices'   => array(
                    'example' => 'Example'
                ),
                'multiple'  => true,
                'data' => array(
                    'example' => true
                )
            ))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB1pi.png

Comment: Can anyone provide some help on ths?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works with:

```
 ->add('technicians', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array(
                  'example' => 'Example'
                ),
             'multiple'  => true,
             'data' => array(
                   'example' => 'example'
              ),
       ))
```

The value for `data` should match the key of the `choices` array.

`true == 1`, that's why your first example was working.